# Nagios: How to determine parameter order check_ssh

Tags: configuration, nagios

My linux box uses a nonstandard port for ssh. Nagios' `check_ssh` (of course) keeps marking the process as critical since it can't connect on that port. The object file `localhost.cfg` allows for parameters to be passed to `check_ssh`.

The documentation uses the example of:

for ...

```
/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_ping -H 192.168.1.2 -w 100.0,90% -c 200.0,60%
```

...use:

```
define service{
    host_name       linuxbox
    service_description PING
    check_command   check_ping!200.0,80%!400.0,40%
    ...
    }
```

However, it doesn't describe in which order to pass parameters. In my `localhost.cfg` I have tried:

```
check_ssh!xxx22!localhost
```

and

```
check_ssh!4!10!OpenSSH_6.7p1!!xxx22!localhost
```

...where xxx22 is the actual port. But it doesn't identify that as the port.

Looking at the `check_ssh` man page doesn't seem to indicate in what order to place these switches...

```
The check_ssh Plugin


    check_ssh v2.2.1.git (nagios-plugins 2.2.1)
    Copyright (c) 1999 Remi Paulmier <remi@sinfomic.fr>
    Copyright (c) 2000-2014 Nagios Plugin Development Team
        <devel@nagios-plugins.org>

    Try to connect to an SSH server at specified server and port


    Usage:
    check_ssh  [-4|-6] [-t <timeout>] [-r <remote version>] [-p <port>] <host>

    Options:
     -h, --help
        Print detailed help screen
     -V, --version
        Print version information
     --extra-opts=[section][@file]
        Read options from an ini file. See
        https://www.nagios-plugins.org/doc/extra-opts.html
        for usage and examples.
     -H, --hostname=ADDRESS
        Host name, IP Address, or unix socket (must be an absolute path)
     -p, --port=INTEGER
        Port number (default: 22)
     -4, --use-ipv4
        Use IPv4 connection
     -6, --use-ipv6
        Use IPv6 connection
     -t, --timeout=INTEGER:<timeout state>
        Seconds before connection times out (default: 10)
        Optional ":<timeout state>" can be a state integer (0,1,2,3) or a state STRING
     -r, --remote-version=STRING
        Alert if string doesn't match expected server version (ex: OpenSSH_3.9p1)
     -P, --remote-protocol=STRING
        Alert if protocol doesn't match expected protocol version (ex: 2.0)
     -v, --verbose
        Show details for command-line debugging (Nagios may truncate output)

    Send email to help@nagios-plugins.org if you have questions regarding use
    of this software. To submit patches or suggest improvements, send email to
    devel@nagios-plugins.org
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a command and use that command for your service.

```
define command{
  command_name check_ssh_2222
  command_line /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_ssh -p 2222 $ARG1
}
```

And then for your service:

```
check_command   check_ssh_2222
```

Comment: Thanks for the post. I tried that as well, but ran into a different issue. Maybe you could look there and get credit for the answer if you have ideas. Thx. `https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/457409/nagios-failing-restart-with-new-service-directove-in-localhost-cfg`

Answer (score 0):

My `/etc/nagios/objects/commands.cfg` states

```
define command{
    command_name    check_ping
    command_line    $USER1$/check_ping -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -w $ARG1$ -c $ARG2$ -p 5
    }
```

which defines the arguments in between the exclamation marks as in the documentation example you gave.
It also tells us that

```
define command{
        command_name    check_ssh
        command_line    $USER1$/check_ssh $ARG1$ $HOSTADDRESS$
        }
```

I think that your entry should be

```
check_ssh!--port=xxx22
```

since there is no predefined argument to specify the port, like `--port=$ARG1$` in the definition, but only a generic place holder.

Edit: I think the localhost should not be part of the `check_ssh!...` line, since nagios will substitute `$HOSTADDRESS$` for the appropriate hosts ip/name.

Comment: Thanks for that. I put in ` check_ssh!--host=localhost!--port=xxx22` and nagios will start with `service nagios restart`. But it still reports the starts (via web interface) as "unknown".

Comment: P.s. at the command line `./check_ssh --host localhost --port xxx22` responds with `./check_ssh --host localhost --port 32122
SSH OK - OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u4 (protocol 2.0) | time=0.007549s;;;0.000000;10.000000` ... so it appears the `check_ssh` parameters themselves are OK...?