# Nagios failing restart with new service directove in localhost.cfg

Tags: configuration, nagios

I started with the default `localhost.cfg` found in `/usr/local/nagios/etc/objects`. I simply added a service field at the top of the appropriate section. I used existing "ping" service section as a template ...

```
###############################################################################
#
# SERVICE DEFINITIONS
#
###############################################################################

# Define a custom service 


define service {

    use                     local-service           ; Name of service template to use
    host_name               localhost
    service_description     docker_testconn
    check_command           check_testconn_xxx22
}

define service {

    use                     local-service           ; Name of service template to use
    host_name               localhost
    service_description     PING
    check_command           check_ping!100.0,20%!500.0,60%
}
```

The `check_testconn_xxx22.sh` lives in `/usr/local/nagios/libexec` and (for testing) simply returns a positive message ....

```
#!/bin/bash
countWarnings=2
if (($countWarnings<=5)); then
                echo "OK - $countWarnings services in Warning state"
                exit 0
        elif ((6<=$countWarnings && $countWarnings<=30)); then
                                # This case makes no sense because it only adds one warning.
                                # It is just to make an example on all possible exits.
                echo "WARNING - $countWarnings services in Warning state"
                exit 1
        elif ((30<=$countWarnings)); then
                echo "CRITICAL - $countWarnings services in Warning state"
                exit 2
        else
                echo "UNKNOWN - $countWarnings"
                exit 3
fi
```

...

```
# ls -la check_testconn_xxx22.sh 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 663 Jul 20 12:07 check_testconn_xxx22.sh

# ./check_testconn_xxx22.sh 
OK - 2 services in Warning state

# echo $?
0

# service nagios restart
Job for nagios.service failed. See 'systemctl status nagios.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.

# journalctl -xn
-- Logs begin at Thu 2018-07-19 16:28:44 CEST, end at Fri 2018-07-20 12:08:21 CEST. --
Jul 20 12:08:21 docker-server-1 nagios[2872]: ***> One or more problems was encountered while running the pre-flight check...
Jul 20 12:08:21 docker-server-1 nagios[2872]: Check your configuration file(s) to ensure that they contain valid
Jul 20 12:08:21 docker-server-1 nagios[2872]: directives and data definitions.  If you are upgrading from a previous
Jul 20 12:08:21 docker-server-1 nagios[2872]: version of Nagios, you should be aware that some variables/definitions
Jul 20 12:08:21 docker-server-1 nagios[2872]: may have been removed or modified in this version.  Make sure to read
Jul 20 12:08:21 docker-server-1 nagios[2872]: the HTML documentation regarding the config files, as well as the
Jul 20 12:08:21 docker-server-1 nagios[2872]: 'Whats New' section to find out what has changed.
Jul 20 12:08:21 docker-server-1 systemd[1]: nagios.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jul 20 12:08:21 docker-server-1 systemd[1]: Failed to start Nagios Core 4.4.1.
-- Subject: Unit nagios.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit nagios.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
```

I can't figure out why nagios is unhappy with that section.

Comment: Check /var/log/nagios/nagios.log. It's normally pretty good at explaning what the issue is.

Comment: From what I remember of nagios, there are more files to touch to create a new command.

Comment: @Raman Sailopal Unfortunately, the nagios log doesn't show anything at the `service nagios restart` command. The `journalctl ` is the only output I get :/

Comment: Have you defined the command in commands.cfg?

Comment: @Raman Sailopal That was it. I had a fatfinger in there and missed it. If you want to make this the answer, I'll give credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the command.cfg config file that sets up all the commands referenced in the localhost.cfg file